# Form submission tag not fired

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, forms

I want to create a goal from google tag manager and link it to google analytics goal event then link it to google ads for `Target CPA`.

I added all images here.
I don't know which part I did wrong (`trigger-tag-google analytics event` or...?)

The google analytics event is:

- Category: `Form Submit`
- Action: `Submit`

Note: the form submission did not give me google variable such as form id or ...

Note: It is strange while the tag not fired but in google analytics goal there are 2 goals added for this goal!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the information from the preview function, the event is not being sent at all as the conditions for the trigger are not met.

In the first, the form is submitted but the page path does not match that specified in the trigger, so the event is not triggered.

In the second, the page path is correct, but the form is not submitted. So again, the event is not triggered.

Based on the page path you are using in the trigger, you've selected the confirmation page that the form sends users to following a successful submission. However, because of that, GTM is listening for the form submission event there, rather than in the place where the form is. That path should be changed to the page on which you can see the actual form.

Alternatively, you could bypass the whole thing and just create a destination based Analytics goal that looks for visits to that confirmation page.

Comment: Perfect answer.

Comment: thanks for the complete answer. I need this goal for google ads and if I just set a goal destination from Google Analytics then how can I define it for google ads conversion? I mean how google ads can find out that this goal destination will make by form submission?

Comment: @akhbarejadid - You should have your Analytics view linked with your Google Ads account. Any goals you have created in Analytics can then be imported into Ads as conversion metrics using the Conversions settings. Here's Google's own instructions for that: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034306?hl=en

Comment: @GeoffAtkins I know how can import goals from analytics to google ads and I already did it. I am wondering how google ads can find out this goal [destination] should create by form submit?

Comment: Ads doesn't necessarily need to know that. Just that it's a goal you want to measure. Analytics doesn't even need to necessarily know that it's a form submit, just that the user has ended up on the confirmation page.